# Is there a way to force the browser to load a link without hitting cache?

Tags: html

I can easily make the browser always request the latest version of a page by appending a timestamp to the query string, for example:

```
onclick="window.open('index.html?t=12343542436')"
```

Is there a way that I could do that without messing with the url? (Which is ugly from a UI point of view--makes sharing links harder)

Comment: Is .htaccess an option? You can prevent specific pages/files from being cached altogether.  I would imagine other servers have something similar as well, but I only know of Apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your server to send cache controls HTTP headers with `.html` file type.

For example, in Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresByType text/html     "access plus 0 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

There's similar config in every server (and even in programming language like PHP or Node.js, etc)

Here an article speaking in depth of the cache related HTTP headers: http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/